# How to subtract a value from a time difference

Tags: mysql, time

I dont know if the question is appropriate, but the situation goes like this:

In my mysql query I am getting the time difference and get the summation for every employees under a common section.

```
SUM(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(fDate, fDateOut))) AS timediff
```

Now, after getting the result, I have to get only the 8 hours from the result and put the excess hours in another column in the table where:

```
example:
fDate                 fDateOut
2013-08-01 07:00      2013-08-01 18:00

timediff = 11 hours    // <------ now I need to get only 8 hours from this result and put the excess in another column:
```

therefore:

```
timediff     = 8 hours
excesstime   = 3 hours
```

How do i do the computation in mysql? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Is your question about how to `INSERT` data into a MySQL table or about how to subtract 8 from 11?

Comment: not about insertion, but about the logic and fastest way how it will be done. sorry for the question...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly crude solution, I'm sure it can be optimised to suit your query, but it shows the idea.

```
SELECT *, LEAST(8,timediff) AS timediff, GREATEST(0,timediff-8) AS excess 
FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(fDate, fDateOut))) AS timediff from test
) t
```

Comment: Did this help at all?